# Why is there a long star field sequence at the beginning of “Star Trek: The Motion Picture?”

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-motion-picture

*Star Trek: The Motion Picture* opens with a long pull back from a field of stars, for almost three minutes, with music playing. The first time I saw it, I kept expecting something to happen, but nothing does. It eventually just fades to black, then we get the opening credits and another field of stars.

Why did they put that part at the start of the movie?

Comment: Wasn't the visual effect similar to Star Wars and Superman?

Comment: @FlaStorm32 Similar to Supermann and to the old spacefield screensavers. Star Wars used a fixed starfield in the background of the opening title/crawl.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 I think, this movie predates the screensavers.

Comment: @Holger is right, this film came out before there were even IBM PC's and the need for screen savers had been established. And back then, this sequence was just _so cool_ as were all the rest of the special effects in the film. It really raised the bar for special effects even though by today's standards they don't seem that impressive any more. I seem to recall a starship coming into view _at the top_ at the end of the sequence though (also totally cool back then).

Comment: It does predate the screensavers but that was just as a comparison for a similar effect compared to Star Wars' static starfield (until the pan up/pan down).

Comment: @user I take it this is first older film you've seen?

Comment: I have “The Sound of Music” on DVD. It not only has an Overture (I’m pretty sure it does, I haven’t played it in a while), but also an “Intermezzo”. Yes, literally orchestral music playing over random helicopter views of hilly landscapes por like 5? minutes straight. Theater-goers had a chance to take a break. It’s an interesting experience. I have no idea how common it was.

Comment: Makes me want to check my copy of _Lawrence of Arabia_ (over 3.5 hours plus intermission) to see whether it includes the overture and intermezzo.

Comment: In the original theatrical 35mm wide release, there were no stars for the overture. Just an absolutely black screen.

Answer (score 68):

### It's called an [Overture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overture#Film), in this case a piece of music called [Ilia's Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mj4z2Y1y2Ak).

The overture is a piece of music, usually containing the main themes of a production's score, that plays prior to the actual production but after the audience has been seated, to help set the mood.

Originally they were part of ballets, operas, et cetera but were adapted to film once the medium took off.

You don't see them very much anymore but as you can see from the list in the link, a lot of the older epic films from the 1950s and 1960s (like *Spartacus*, *Ben-Hur*, *The Ten Commandments*, and *Lawrence of Arabia*) had them. *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* is on the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_with_overtures) in the “After 1970” section.

Comment: I think this is the best answer and I think it’s worth noting that this overture is much shorter than the ones that preceded it in both film and stage works.

Comment: Some, yes. It's only a little shorter than El Cid (less than 20 seconds depending on the OST version), for example, but half the length of Ben-Hur's. But it seems most are quite long at four minutes or more. I guess that back then, you didn't have all the ads and things before the film came on, so it let people a bit late to get a seat before the titles rolled.

Comment: someone please give one more upvote to this answer and make it perfect

Comment: Robert Wise, a very "old school" director, was a fan of overtures and many or most of his other filems -- including West Side Story (1961) and The Sand Pebbles (1965) -- also begin with these long stretches of music. (The composer for ST:TMP, Jerry Goldsmith, also did the track for The Sand Pebbles.) The theatrical release of ST:TMP did not have the receding starfield -- that was added for the 2001 director's cut -- so it played while the screen was blank or still covered by curtains. I do recall seeing the movie in the theater as a child and thinking that the projector must have been broken.

Comment: I recall that in movies such as Ben-Hur and Gone with the Wind, there is text "OVERTURE" displayed on screen while the overture is playing. But for Star Trek TMP there is no such text, leading to people such as the OP being confused.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to SpaceWolf1701’s details [in their answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/267040/14850), a film overture like this had a more practical reason as explained in this [2018 Atlantic article](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2018/10/why-filmmakers-should-bring-back-musical-overtures/572560/) that focuses on overtures in film; bold emphasis is mine:

> “The movie overture—music set against a blank screen or still images before the drama unfolds—all but disappeared from film sometime in the 1970s. Once a Hollywood mainstay, **overtures evolved naturally from their use in opera and road shows, giving moviegoers time to find their seats and settle in before the main feature.** But these musical pastiches also served an important cinematic function: They allowed audiences a chance to put aside their thoughts of the outside world. With curtains drawn and house lights dimmed, overtures drew moviegoers in, and inward, toward a space of anticipation.”

You need to think back to 1979 when *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* came out: Cable wasn’t as pervasive and easily accessible as it now is and video tape players were not as common-place either.

Unless you were located in an area where cable was common-place — or you were financially well off — video tape sales/rentals and cable were not the normal ways the vast majority of people watched movies. And yes, movies were broadcast on plain-old broadcast TV. But if you wanted to intentionally see a new film that was not on TV — and not interrupted by commercials — chances are you had to go to a movie theater.

For the vast majority of people, if they wanted watch a movie in 1979, they simply had to go to an actual movie theater and sit down in a seat and wait for the film to start.

So the purpose of an overture in this case was to allow the expected crowds of people swarming in to see the highly anticipated first Star Trek film on screen find a seat and sit down. And it would also serve as s signal for anyone in the lobby to come into the theater because the movie was about to start.

Flash forward to now, and this overture seems incredibly tedious and ponderous. But in my humble opinion, the whole of *Star Trek: The Motion Picture* is incredibly tedious and ponderous. With pacing and long shots that bored me as a kid and make little sense as an adult.

---

#### Warning: Slight tangent ahead.

##### Minimized to avoid overwhelming the core answer above.

<sup>As cool as some of the special effects were, the storytelling in this film is truly a chore to watch and while it made back its investment at the box office, it was a critical failure.</sup>

<sup>And in retrospect, the seemingly never-ending overture coupled with similarly seemingly never-ending effects shots make me think reflects the delusion (arrogance?) of the studio — and Gene Roddenberry himself — that somehow *Star Wars* was an aberration and what the world was waiting for was a grand, new *Star Trek* film.</sup>

<sup>Remember, while Gene Roddenberry was trying to get *Star Trek* back on TV in the 1970s via [*Star Trek: Phase II*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Phase_II), *Star Wars* came along in 1977 and not only changed the film game but also dethroned *Star Trek* as the best known science-fiction property in pop culture. So suddenly *Star Trek: Phase II* was reworked and reimagined into the film known as… *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*.</sup>

<sup>I can imagine Gene Roddenberry himself thinking, “Wow! So many people will be clamoring to get into the theater to see this masterpiece that I *must* pad the front of the film with a few minutes of nothing to give them time to get a seat and enjoy the greatest science-fiction film ever!”</sup>

Comment: The editorializing doesn't help the answer and is somewhat contradicted by the demand for the Director's Cut, the remaster, and a theatrical rerelease earlier this year.

Comment: There were movies on TV "back in the olden days" of the 1970s.  It's not like there was nothing to watch.  When I was a kid in the 1970s, Friday night was movie and popcorn night at home in front of the TV.

Comment: The intro to a movie wasn't there for people to get into the theater and find a seat.  By the time the intro started, everybody was already there and had already sat through the advertisements.  The intro was when you settled down and started paying attention - the advertisements were done and the movie was starting.

Comment: I think they were going for a "2001" style with the long slow special effects shots. By the time it was released moviegoers had moved beyond that spectacle and preferred faster action shots.

Comment: In 1979, excepting a few trailers, there were no ads

Comment: @Yorik And I was referring to pictures in the 1950s and '60s, when the Epic Film with the overture, the Intermission, and Exit Music were in their heyday. One or two trailers MAYBE, depending, and then the film. Plus you had roadshow versions where you'd have an intermission inserted into a film that might not have it to begin with (like they do with the Lord of the Rings extended editions or the director's cut of Kingdom of Heaven, which is explicitly referred to as a roadshow version in my answer's link). Those were intended from the get-go to seem more upscale, like an opera or a ballet.

Comment: I think the tangent is actually the most important part.  This was a TV episode script made into a movie; they had to find ways to pad the length.

Comment: Rewatching it now, I'd agree with ponderous. But I remember seeing it in the cinema when I was a teenager, and the sheer scale of the Enterprise during the "Kirk Arrives" scene, and then later the vast size of the V'Ger ship against the minuscule Enterprise was breathtaking. I went home and told my long-suffering mother all about it in breathless detail. I was pretty surprised when I later heard that it had received negative criticism. Watching now, it's obvious why: very indulgent, yes, quite weak. But back then, I'd never seen anything like it.

Comment: @JRE I'm with you.  In 1979 our family had cable, and a movie channel was included in the basic package.  Every month there would be a new selection of movies, repeated multiple times so you'd always get a chance to see everything.  And we weren't rich.

Comment: @MarkRansom, cable existed in 1979, but as far as I know it was only in select cities. The places I lived didn't get it until a few years (almost a decade for the most rural places) later.

Comment: @ThePhoton you're right, I forgot about the uneven rollout of cable.  I know our little suburb got it long before the big city we were next to, because of all the politics involved with granting a monopoly to such a large captive audience.